# Negation verb in sql query

Tags: sql

My question is simple. How can I compose a query in which I negate something? And I'm not refer to NOT condition. For example I have to select all the tourists that booked at least one pension(acc_type_code) whose rating is greater than 9, but did not book any 3 star hotel with a rating less than 9?

My tables:

Tourist

```
id (pk)
name
email
```

Booking

```
id_tourist (pk)
id_accomodation (pk)
```

Accomodation

```
id_accomodation (pk)
acc_type_code (fk)
nr_of_stars
rating
price
```

Accomodation type

```
acc_type_cde (pk)
acc_type_name
```

What I've tried:

```
SELECT t.id as id_tourist, t.name, t.email from Tourist t,
JOIN Booking b on (t.id = b.id_tourist)
JOIN Accomodation a on (b.id_accomodation = a.id_accomodation)
JOIN AccType at on (a.acc_type_code = at.acc_type_code)
WHERE a.rating > 9 AND .. ?
```

And here I'm blocked. Any suggestions?

Comment: use NOT EXISTS...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to locate the records you want to exclude from your query, and then filter them out in the `WHERE` condition

```
SELECT t.id as id_tourist, t.name, t.email 
FROM Tourist t
INNER JOIN Booking b on (t.id = b.id_tourist)
INNER JOIN Accomodation a on (b.id_accomodation = a.id_accomodation)
INNER JOIN AccType at on (a.acc_type_code = at.acc_type_code)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Accomodate a2 on (b.id_accomodation = a2.id_accomodation) AND a2.nr_of_stars = 3 AND a2.rating < 9
WHERE a.rating > 9 AND a2.id_accomodation IS NULL
```

NOTE:  The above syntax assumes MSSQL is your SQL flavor.

### Update

based on further info from OP in comments, `NOT EXISTS` would likely provide a simpler approach.  The concept is similar:  Locate the records you want to exclude, and wrap then in a `NOT EXISTS` clause

```
SELECT t.id as id_tourist, t.name, t.email 
FROM Tourist t
INNER JOIN Booking b on (t.id = b.id_tourist)
INNER JOIN Accomodation a on (b.id_accomodation = a.id_accomodation)
INNER JOIN AccType at on (a.acc_type_code = at.acc_type_code)
WHERE a.rating > 9 
AND NOT EXISTS ( 
     SELECT b2.id_tourist FROM Booking b2 
     INNER JOIN Accomodation a2 on (b2.id_accomodation = a2.id_accomodation)
     WHERE a2.nr_of_stars = 3 AND a2.rating < 9
)
```

NOTE:  You may need to add more joins inside the `NOT EXISTS` clause to locate the records that should be excluded.  I don't know your data.

Comment: It doesn't work. If I have a user named ana: id=1, in booking: 1-1, 1-3, 1-4 and in accomodation: id_acc: 1, nr_star: 3, rating 7, id_acc:3, nr_star:3, rating 17 and id_acc:4, nr_star =1, rating: 1, the user is displayed when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

should be easy as using a NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT t.id as id_tourist, t.name, t.email from Tourist t,
JOIN Booking b on (t.id = b.id_tourist)
JOIN Accomodation a on (b.id_accomodation = a.id_accomodation)
JOIN AccType at on (a.acc_type_code = at.acc_type_code)
WHERE a.rating > 9 AND 
NOT EXISTS (
your query to get the same tourist_Id and has booked a 3 start hotel and under 9 ratings
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a `LEFT JOIN`, anti-join method:

```
SELECT t.id as id_tourist, t.name, t.email 
FROM Tourist t,
JOIN Booking b ON t.id = b.id_tourist
JOIN Accomodation a ON b.id_accomodation = a.id_accomodation
                   AND a.rating > 9
JOIN AccType at ON a.acc_type_code = at.acc_type_code
LEFT JOIN (SELECT t.id
           FROM Tourist t
           JOIN Booking b ON t.id = b.id_tourist
           JOIN Accomodation a ON b.id_accomodation = a.id_accomodation
                              AND a.rating < 9
                              AND a.nr_of_stars = 3
          ) a2 ON a2.id = t.id
WHERE a2.id IS NULL
```

The outer query finds only tourists (`t.id`) that booked a hotel above a 9 rating.  The inner query finds only tourists (`t.id`) that booked a 3 star hotel, below a 9 rating.

By doing a `LEFT JOIN` between them, and limiting our results only to those that do not match (`WHERE a2.id IS NULL`) we are left with only those that booked a hotel above a 9 rating, and did not book a 3 star hotel with a rating below 9.

Comment: This is a copy of devlin's answer which was posted 4 minutes earlier.

Comment: @DanBracuk Please remove your downvote if it is yours, or explain how this is a duplicate.  It's my opinion that you've downvoted the correct answer, and OP probably didn't try it because of that or your comment.